# T/F: The set: $\{(x,y): \sin(x^{2012} +y^3) + x^2 + y^4 \le 1\}$ is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, compactness

> T/F: The set: $\{(x,y): \sin(x^{2012} +y^3) + x^2 + y^4 \le 1\}$ is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I think it is false since I don't believe the set is closed nor bounded? Is that correct?

Comment: If either $|x| > \sqrt{2}$ or $|y| > \sqrt[4]{2}$, then the left side is strictly bigger than $1$. So the set is contained in $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}] \times [-\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[4]{2}]$, and thus, the set is in fact bounded.

Comment: The set is certainly bounded.  All points are inside the square $[-2, 2] \times [2,2]$

Comment: Certainly $x^2+y^4$ and $x^{2012}+y^3$ are continuous functions, so $f(x,y)=\sin(x^{2012} +y^3) + x^2+y^4$ is also continuous. So your set is just $f^{-1}((-\infty,1]))$. But since $(-\infty,1]$ is closed then by continuity $f^{-1}((-\infty,1]))$ is also closed. Since $\sin$ is bounded, we need $x^2+y^4 \in [0,2]$ so this set is bounded.